# which way is better in a frequently write case with thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, performance

We need to write some data into a file at about 100ms interval for about 30 minutes and then wait for a while, and repeat again. Our application is a C#, .net 3.5 application. The data is small for each write , less than 1MB. Right now we get a thread from the Threadpool and let that thread to write into the file each time when a new data is received (at about 100ms interval).

There is another way to do this, I think. We can get a thread from Threadpool at beginning and keep that thread running during the entire writing session. When that thread finished a write, let it wait for next signal to get updated data from a shared place and write again. The downside of this way is we need to synchroized the shared data object to make sure it will not be overwriten by the the new data if the writting is slower. then it may slow down the communication which the data is transferred from another system.

I don't have time to write code test them yet. do you think it is worthy to test them? or it is obviously one way is better than another?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a producer/consumer pattern, so a thread can have the file locked all the time and you don't need to open and close the FileStream.

Here an example: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/deadlocks.shtml

(in the "More Monitor methods" section)

Comment: Also if you're receiving data a little at a time, you don't need to write as soon as you get the data. It may be more efficient to buffer and do larger writes less frequently.

Answer (score 0):

If you think that you might have contention writing to your file, then a single thread writer is a good idea. Otherwise, there is no real problem dispatching a single operation to a miscellanous thread imo.